# Viewing a separate PDF in Texmaker

Tags: pdf

I like the functionality where I can type my tex file and compile it and have it show up on the right, but would like if I could switch between viewing my compiled pdf and viewing a separate pdf (in this case, a textbook pdf with the exercises in it). Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have not TeXmaker available on my system and can not test it. But a hack I can imagine:

is to open a new main.tex file, and to create a code containing an `\includepdf` command like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},width=\textwidth]{Exercises.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Then, I suppose that by switching between the files, you can view the book "Exercises" in your viewer (well... it's clone!)

Comment: I prefer to just open the other PDF in a different viewer - and since I have two monitors on my desktop PC, that makes it easy to see both PDFs at once.

Comment: me too with one monitor @alephzero. But is this another answer? I suppose no.