# subfile Option output name

Tags: subfiles

I am using the package `subfiles` in MikTeX (with XeLaTeX). It works like a charm, but I would like to display the compiled subfile in MikTex as PDF. This is common in MikTeX: The editor opens a PDF Preview window to display the PDF with the same base name after compiling.

For example: After compiling main.tex, main.pdf is displayed.

But compiling a subfile outputs the pdf as main.pdf too. Thus, there is no PDF preview of the compiled subfile.

For example: After compiling the subfile mySubfile.tex (of main.tex), the result is saved as main.pdf, hence the editor does not find a file mySubfile.pdf to display in the preview window.

How to tell `subfiles` to use the subfile's base name as PDF output base name when compiling a subfile?

I know that I could change the output name somehow generally in the MikTeX options or in the compiler's options, but this would make it impossible to switch easily between compiling a subfile and compiling the main file.

Comment: This is a matter of your editor and `subfiles` package or any other package can not do much on your problem. See a way in my answer (but sure needs more compilations and may be doesn't fit your needs)

Comment: Relative https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450653/120578 if not a dupplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just open the file in another viewer. In linux it would refresh automatically but in other OSs I am not sure. Having it open I could just press it's button from the taskbar and see it.

I am sure this is not the answer you are looking for, so, independent from your editor
you can use this way:

You can create a main.tex file that will be the one to use for the pdf preview.
This file will have a code like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},width=\textwidth]{CurrentFile.pdf}
\end{document}
```

This will be the main file that you will have opened with your editor.

Then you will open any other file you want and compile. After every compilation you have to change back to the `main.tex` and compile with the name `CurrentFile` changed to your any other file you want to be appeared in the editor's preview. The real mainfile can be supposed to be one of any other files too.